# Internal server error in jquery ajax request

Tags: asp.net, ajax, c#-3.0

I'm having a problem with my jquery ajax request .I'm getting this error when the function triggers

**{"Message":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.","StackTrace":"   at Test.Web.Ajax.Test(String var1, String var2, Int32 var3, Int32 var4, String var5, String var6, String fvar7, String var8, String var9, String var10, String var11, String var12, Boolean var13)","ExceptionType":"System.NullReferenceException"}**

My post JSON is given below

```
{"var1":"2","var2":"1","var3":0,"var4":20,"var5":"","var6":"","var7":"0","var8":"","var9":"","var10":"","var11":"","var12":"","var13":true}
```

The client side function

```
function test(var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,var6,var7,var8,var9,var10,var11,var12,var13){

 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajax.aspx/Test",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ var1: var1, var2: var2, var3: var3, var4: var4, var5: var5, var6: var6, var7: var7, var8:var8, var9: var9, var10: var10, var11: var11, var12: var12, var13: var13}),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(response) {
                         //more stuff
                    }
                });

}
```

server side function

```
        [WebMethod]
        public static ArrayList Test(string var1,string var2, int var3, int var4, string var5, string var6, string var7, string var8, string var9, string var10, string var11,string var12, bool var13)
        {

//more stuff
}
```

my json post object is not null but still I'm getting this error I dont know how to fix this.. please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check whether there is any situation in your code that will throw similar exception(Nullreferenceexception) because you are playing with empty string in your WebMethod

If this is the problem with Jquery Ajax post you might get a invalidacastexception or internal server error not a null reference exception.

Anyway i am including the script for ajax call below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                test(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 99, 999, true);
            });

            function test(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7, var8, var9, var10, var11, var12) {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Default.aspx/Test",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ var1: var1, var2: var2, var3: var3, var4: var4, var5: var5, var6: var6, var7: var7, var8: var8, var9: var9, var10: var10, var11: var11, var12: var12 }),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert('success');
                        //more stuff
                    },
                    error: function (xhr) {
                        alert('error');
                        alert(xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
            }

        </script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I''m sorry for the confusion I just edited my question..still its not working for me

Comment: can you please post how you calling that jquery method test?

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
                test("2", "1",0,20, " ", " ", " ", " "," "." "," "," ",true);
            });

Comment: still i don't have any problem. Can i take a look at your Routeconfig class ?

Comment: I dont have one I'm using webforms

Comment: which version are you using ?

Comment: do you have a App_Start folder in your project ?

Comment: did you try put a model instead of parameters in [WebMethod] ?

Comment: are you getting parameter values to the WebMethod? did you try debug it?

Comment: yes I tried that .Its working in my local pc but when I place this build in server I'm getting this error

Comment: I dont think so .I'm getting correct output in local

Comment: If this is the problem with Jquery Ajax post you might get a invalidacastexception or internal server error not a null reference exception.

Comment: you are right There was problem in my webmethod .thank you for pointing out that can you update the answer with your previous comment after that I will mark it as answer